# In Influxdb, How to delete all measurements?

Tags: influxdb

I know `DROP MEASUREMENT measurement_name` used to drop single measurement. How to delete all measurements at once ?

Comment: for future myself: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/database_management/#drop-series-from-the-index-with-drop-series

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Theres no way to drop all of the measurements directly, but the query below will achieve the same result.

```
DROP SERIES FROM /.*/
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I wanted to only delete one measurement not all, how do I choose to delete all data within a single measurement?

Answer (score 7):

For those who are looking to use `WHERE` clause with `DROP SERIES`, here it is:

`DROP SERIES FROM /.*/ WHERE "your-tag" = 'tag-value-to-delete-data'`

Please notice the quotation marks on after the `WHERE` clause, they should be like this for `DROP SERIES`; as of `InfluxDB v.1.3`.

Else, you might get error like `ERR: invalid expression: ...`

Answer (score 0):

The way to delete all entries of one MEASUREMENT is

DELETE FROM MEASUREMENT_NAME

Answer (score 0):

clear bucket in command line:
influx delete --bucket 'mybucket' --org 'myorg' --start 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z --stop $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

Answer (score -2):

use "DELETE Measurement" from InfluxDB admin Panel