# In InfluxDB, how to delete entire measurements using regex?

Tags: influxdb

`Drop from <measurement_name>` is used in InfluxDB to delete a all points from a specific measurement. You can also delete all measurements at once using regex (see [In Influxdb, How to delete all measurements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587898/in-influxdb-how-to-delete-all-measurements)).

But, how do I delete all points from all measurements starting with a specific string?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed to solve my specific problem:

`Delete from /<starting_string>*/`

of course it can be generalized to any applicable regex - just be sure to start and end your expression with `/`.

Hope that helps someone out there!